# How to create Json Objects in JMeter

Tags: json, rest, object, jmeter

I've been using jmeter for a week now. I am working on creating a test where you compare REST API vs the database. now REST result is json but not my database result. How can i create an json object for my database results? Thanks in advance!

Comment: would it be easier to extract the json using regex, then compare it to the DB result? - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20916699/regular-expression-to-extract-json-string-from-text

Comment: @CharlieS the db isn't exactly look like its REST counter part. the db needs to be transformed into something else. the db results dont have dates while the rest api got dates.

Comment: Of course the DB isn't REST. You need to convert one or the other (or both) to compare. Does it matter which is converted? Why convert DB into JSON? You obviously can't invent data so you can only compare the fields that are included in both responses.

Comment: Problem with creating JSON object is order of fields, whitespace, etc.  You will still need to write a comparison method to consume both JSON objects.
JMeter does not have JSON methods, but you can import java factory/builder classes, and create JSON from those.

Comment: How are you getting the results from the DB?

Answer (score 0):

Use Bean Shell Sampler, write your own code to convert DB values in to JSON format.

Comparison can be done using Assertion.

Reference link: [Converting the Database details to JSON object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21110537/converting-the-database-details-to-json-object)

Hope this will help.

Comment: That what i've been doing. but i don't know how to convert it to Json format